# Maven dependency works from Maven-local but not when I deploy the aar to repository

Tags: maven, android-studio, aar

Whenever I sync my project using online repository the Class reference is lost even when Android Studio correctly tells that the repository was found. So build fails

When the same artifact is deployed in maven local everything works correctly.  (or viceversa, I first deploy local , test everything ok but when I upload the project fails).

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `pro-guard` file was still empty so the exported `aar` had no files, I had to place default lib annotations for it to export classes.